# React components how to execute a button that calls a function from a different component

Tags: react-redux, reactjs

i've been trying to execute a button that calls a function from a different component.

```js
import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB '
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class ComponentA extends Component {
    render() {
        return 
        (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click me</button>    
        );
    }
}

export default ComponentA;
```

this didn't work out. the button wasnt able to call the function. what am i doing wrong?

```js
import React, {
  Component
}
from 'react';

class ComponentB extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
}
handleClick() {
  console.log("hi hi hi");
}
}

export
default ComponentB;
```

Comment: How are ComponentA and ComponentB related? If ComponentA is included in ComponentB as a child, you can use props, otherwise you need to pass control of this to whatever component is the common ancestor of ComponentA and ComponentB

Comment: i've imported ComponentB in ComponentA import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB '; in

Comment: I mean what does your JSX look like? Is `ComponentA` used in `ComponentB`'s `render()` call?

Comment: no actually i just called the button onClick function. onClick={this.handleClick}. i have no idea how to do it im new to react i was following the react docs snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing `ComponentB`, but not using it, that's why is not working. In your case the best way is to implement the `handleClick` directly to your ComponentA, but this is not what you wanna do. If you're looking to share the same functions with different components, using `redux` together with react js will get the job done and will provided to the other components as well ;)